# How to set the datapump path in the database dynamically?

Tags: oracle12c, datapump

Actually data pump requires the dump directories to be set in the database. I need to set a data pump path dynamically. Also without overwriting the existing dump files.
Something like this:
Echo(Create Directory xxdmp AS '/opt/oracle'; 
Echo Grant read,write ON Directory dmpdir TO scott;)
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump

Comment: Are you using shell script to invoke the sqlplus?

Comment: yes i am using batch script